# Find a perpendicular vector

Tags: linear-algebra

suppose $v$ is a vector of dimension $n$ and $v(i)=n+1-2i$, $1 \leq i \leq n$. How would I find a vector $u$ that is perpendicular to it and also to the vector $v_2$ whose co-ordinates are all constant $1$ (as in $v_2(i)=1$ for all $1 \leq i \leq n$)?

I tried doing $v(i)\cdot u(i)=0$ as in $(n+1-2i)x=0$ but that is too general to be able to help.

Comment: You should start with 2D vectors first, then move to 3D vectors, ... then you might see a pattern.

Comment: What do you mean? Can I have a starting example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lets start with n = 2: $v_1=[1,-1]^T$, $v_2=[1,1]^T$. Lets use the dot product with $u=[a,b]^T$.

You will get two equations:

$$v_1\cdot u = a-b=0$$
$$v_2\cdot u = a+b=0$$

From this you can conclude that only $u=[0,0]^T$ solves this problem.

For n = 3: $v_1=[2,0,-2]^T$. Again we can use the dot product.

$$v_1\cdot u=2a+0b-2c=0$$
$$v_2\cdot u=a+b+c=0$$

Just continue this type of analysis and maybe you will see a way to find a vector for every n. If you are only looking for one vector, then you can simplyfy your problem by setting almost all components of $u$ to zero.

Comment: From the examples I continued until $n=6$ and got that the first equation is $5a + 3b + c - d - 3e - 5f = 0$ and $a+b+c+d+e+f=0$, so after this pattern I thought that what im looking for is $u(i)=n-1-2i$, but that came out non-perpendicular to $v_1$.... what's wrong?

Comment: I seem not to be able to find some general form for a general $n$...

Answer (score 1):

Let $v$ and $v_2$ be as in your question. That $u$ should be perpendicular to $v_2$ tells us that $$u \cdot v_2 = \sum_{i = 1}^n u_i = 0$$

We ask also for $u$ to be perpendicular to $v$: $$ u \cdot v = \sum_{i = 1}^n (n+1-2i)u_i = 0$$ With the first condition, we may split the sum $$\sum_{i = 1}^n (n+1-2i)u_i = n\sum_{i = 1}^n u_i + \sum_{i = 1}^n u_i - \sum_{i = 1}^n 2iu_i = 0 + 0 - \sum_{i = 1}^n 2iu_i$$ Hence we ask that $$\sum_{i =1}^n u_i = 0 \quad \text{and}\quad \sum_{i=1}^n iu_i = 0 $$ Since you are free to choose your vector, let $u_i = 0$ for $i = 4,5,\dots,n$. You need to solve $$ u_1 + u_2 + u_3 = 0 \quad \text{and}\quad u_1 + 2u_2 + 3u_3 = 0$$ $u_1 = u_3 = 1$ and $u_2 = -2$ will do.